# Left side of assignment operator must be variable or property

Tags: flash, for-loop, actionscript-2

I am trying to assign true/ false using for loop

```
    for (i=1;i<31;i++){
            _global.level + i + Access = true;
    }
```

and got error as "Left side of assignment operator must be variable or property" any help

Comment: try `_global["level" + i].Access`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the value for properties like `level1Access`, `level2Access` ... give

```
_global["level" + i + "Access"] = true;
```

or if the properties are like `level1.Access`, `level2.Access` ... give

```
_global["level" + i].Access = true;
```

or if `Access` is another variable

```
_global["level" + i + Access] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks Diode '_global["level" + i + "Access"] = true;' worked

Answer (score 0):

Look at what the error is telling you. Is this a variable or property

```
_global.level + i + Access //the left hand side of the assignment
```

Until more detail about what `level` and `Access` are is given there's not much help we can give.

A solution might be, (making a guess that level is and array and Access is a property)

```
_global.level[i].Access = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The left hand side needs to be a single variable. When you say `_global.level + i + Access = true;` what do you expect to happen? Which variable should be assigned to true?